# Update Sharepoint List Item with Javascript Client Side Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, csom, list-item

For the past days I've been trying, with no success, to establish a connection to a sharepoint list (https://mywebsite.com/sites/concasbkcu/Lists/list_teste/AllItems.aspx) and update its items with the follow code:

```
var siteUrl= 'https://mywebsite.com/sites/concasbkcu/';
var targetlistItem;
var itemID = 1;

function updateListItem() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('list_teste');

targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemID);

targetList.set_item('Title', 'Test Title');

targetList.update();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);

}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed() {

    alert('Request failed');
}
```

I tried calling this function on a html button, but it just doesn't work...no error message is shown and the item doesn't update at all. Can someone help me, please?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code as below.. It will work.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
        {
            $("#UpdateButton").click(function(){
                SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', updatelistitem);            
            });
        });
        var oListItem ="";
        function updatelistitem() { 
        var itemid = "1";
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('City');  
        oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemid); 
        oListItem.set_item('Title', 'New City Name');
        oListItem.set_item('Status', 'InActive');
        oListItem.update();  
        clientContext.load(oListItem);  
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded,onQueryFailed);  
    }  
        function onQuerySucceeded() {           
            alert("Item Updated Sussefully !!!");
        }
        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {  
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you need to use

```
targetListItem.set_item('Title', 'Test Title');

targetListItem.update();
```

instead of

```
targetList.set_item('Title', 'Test Title');

targetList.update();
```

And change `clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);` to `clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);`

Comment: Hi Michael! Thanks for you answer, id didn't however, work for me...still no message appears and the item isn't updated :(

Comment: Press F12, check if there is any error in console.

Comment: Hi Michael, it appeared to me: Uncaught ReferenceError: SP is not defined
    at updateListItem (tst.js:7)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index_teste.html:50)

Comment: Where did you run the code? You should add the code in a classic sharepoint page.

Comment: I'm running on a sharepoint page...